# Error in 'Redirect to a page when clicked on a row, enable a button when checkbox clicked.'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have an **HTML table**. It shows data from database. **7 columns.** (One of them is a checkbox)

There's a button outside of the table.
**Delete users**  button is initially disabled.

```
<a id="deleteuser" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm disabled" ><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete users</a>
```

It gets enabled when a checkbox is clicked.
My **Checkbox**:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" id="chk>
```

**jQuery** for enabling/disabling button:

```
$(function(){
var button=$('#deleteuser');
button.attr('disabled','disabled');
$('#chk').change(function(e){
if(this.checked){
button.removeAttr('disabled');
} else {
button.attr('disabled','disabled');
}
});
});
```

It's fine till now. Now I've to add one more functionality to this table. When any row is clicked, contents of that row has to redirect to another page so that I can modify that data.

To make table click-able, I used this **CSS**:

```
<style>
    table, table tr, table tr td { cursor: pointer;}
</style>
```

And to edit a particular row, I redirect that row's content (based on User id) to another page. Script I used:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('table.table tr').click(function () {

        window.location='edituserdata.php'
    });

});
```

**----------THE PROBLEM--------------**

Now when I click on a row, I get redirected to edituserdata.php (**even when I click a checkbox**). I want to **enable delete user button when I click a checkbox** and to **redirect to another page when I click on any other columns in that row**. I went wrong somewhere...can't figure it out.
Anyone to help??? Both works, but doesn't work together.

JSFiddle:

[http://jsfiddle.net/iamsajeev/8eMDG/](http://jsfiddle.net/iamsajeev/8eMDG)

Answer (score 0):

you can check the target click event of the row by checking the target nodeName
and prevent further task if it is an anchor. you can also check the checkbox.

```
$('table.table tr').click(function (ev) {
    if(ev.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "a") return;
    if(ev.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "input")return;
});
```

I believe you can also use `is` to check the element.

```
$('table.table tr').click(function (ev) {
    if($(ev.target).is("a")) return;
    if($(ev.target).is("input[type=checkbox]"))return;
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/besabestin/wrPbv/1/)

Comment: don't forget to pass the event, ev at the function. if you pass that there is nothing wrong with this.

Comment: Sorry brother. i passed the event as you said. It didn't work out.

Comment: there you go. check the fiddle.